# How to find out which process is deleting a file without root permissions?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am manually running a program in a cluster by copying the executable file to each node, running it and them copying back the output to the server node. Suddenly, I noticed that a file that takes part in all this process is being deleted consistently and I cannot find out where I am doing that or at least which script is deleting it.

This is related to the question in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608486/how-to-find-which-process-removing-a-directory-in-linux

but notice that here I can replicate the problem. I don't have admin rights so I cannot use `auditd` but I can repeat the process much as I want. Interestingly, I just tried changing the permissions of the file and it keeps vanishing.

I am not expecting anything magical like

```
$ please tell me who did
```

it but I am happy to listen to clever ideas on how to try to tackle this.

btw, I asked the admin whether any process might be deleting the file and he said that that is not possible.

NOTE: I originally posted this in SO but was tagged as offtopic

EDIT: Ok, from what I can see using Mark Plotnick suggestion `strace`, I see that first I there is a call to `gcc` where the `.c` file is compiled. Then there is a `lstat` on the executable. And then it appears on an `execve` call to `/usr/bin/ld` which has the PID of the unlink:

```
5980 execve("/usr/bin/ld", ["/usr/bin/ld", "-plugin", "/cm/local/apps/gcc/6.3.0/libexec"..., "-plugin-opt=/cm/local/apps/gcc/6"..., "-plug       in-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc"..., "-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc", "-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_"..., "-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc",        "-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc", "-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_"..., "--eh-frame-hdr", "-m", "elf_x86_64", "-dynamic-linker", "/lib64       /ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "-o", "MY/EXECUTABLE/BEING/DELETED", "/lib/../lib64/crt1.o", "/lib/../lib64/crti.o", "/cm/local/apps/gcc/6.3.0/lib/g       cc"..., "-L/cm/shared/apps/slurm/17.02.2/"..., "-L/cm/local/apps/gcc/6.3.0/lib/g"..., "-L/cm/local/apps/gcc/6.3.0/lib/g"..., "-L/lib/../lib       64", "-L/usr/lib/../lib64", "-L/cm/shared/apps/slurm/17.02.2/"..., "-L/cm/shared/apps/slurm/17.02.2/"..., "-L/cm/local/apps/gcc/6.3.0/lib/g       "..., "/tmp/ccdL3Sax.o", "-lm", "-lgcc", "--as-needed", ...], [/* 39 vars */]) = 0
```

and then:

```
5980  stat("MY/EXECUTABLE/BEING/DELETED", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=17392, ...}) = 0
5980  lstat("MY/EXECUTABLE/BEING/DELETED", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=17392, ...}) = 0
5980  unlink("MY/EXECUTABLE/BEING/DELETED") = 0
5980  open("MY/EXECUTABLE/BEING/DELETED", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
```

Comment: Try using auditd, it can watch directory content.

Comment: well, I said that in the question, I can't without permissions

Comment: If you think the deletion is the result of a command that you ran or a child process of that command, you can run `strace -f -o /path/to/outputfile -e trace=file yourcommand ...` and then look in the output file for anything that accesses the file you're interested in. (That is literally the word `file` in the argument to strace -e )

Comment: Try `chmod -w` on the parent directory of the file (or try asking the admin to set the immutable attribute on the file) and see if any script errors out? (Note that this is different from changing the file permissions, as it is the directory permissions that control ability to delete)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That seems really the right choice. I am trying it, but the output until my file is deleted has half a million lines and it is a bit cryptic to me. The name of the file in question appears in `lstat() execve() stat() unlink() open() chmod()` any idea what should I look for when it is being deleted?

Comment: To find the executable that deleted the file: Open the log file in an editor, find the line that shows the `unlink` of the file in question, note the PID in the first column. Then search backward in the log file for the `execve` call for that PID. Or, `grep ^the-pid the-logfile | grep execve`

Comment: Ok, So now I see a call to the gnu linker associated to that PID. The linker is deleting the file? This doesn't make much sense to me.  (I'm adding information in a new EDIT)

Comment: The ld option `-o MY/EXCECUTABLE/BEING/DELETED` means "write the new executable to that file". One way a program could do that would be to open the file for writing, but that might fail if the file is currently being executed, which isn't uncommon for an executable. So ld removes the file and then creates a new file with the same name.

Comment: Certainly something like that was happening. It's strange though because the script was compiling only one before the loop but the file would disappear after some successful runs (using still the old executable?), or there's something I don't really see. In any case, I removed that line from the script and it works nicely. I would be happy to accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/939600/how-to-get-notified-when-a-specific-file-is-deleted-in-linux